# opencv_python build error on visual studio 11 and windows 7

Tags: python, visual-studio, opencv, image-processing, cmake

While I was building `opencv 3.2.0` with **python support** from source with `opencv_contrib` and `visual studio 11` I had one error in `cv2.cpp`  which is bellow and I could not find any help online

```
1>------ Build started: Project: opencv_python2, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  cv2.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xmemory0(605): error C2129: static function 'PyObject *pyopencv_from<cv::Matx44d>(const T &)' declared but not defined
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=cv::Matx44d
1>          ]
1>          C:\Users\tofaa\Downloads\Compressed\opencv\sources\opencv-3.2.0\opencv-3.2.0\modules\python\src2\cv2.cpp(207) : see declaration of 'pyopencv_from'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 101 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because pyopencv_cv_ppf_match_3d_ppf_match_3d_ICP_registerModelToScene does not know what to do with 4x4 matrix when it calls pyopencv_from func.
You need to add s stub(!) to 
modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp
something like "code" below, until developer add real function. Do not forget that something will go wrong because of this stub. 
Also this is the answer to all who ignores warning during make:
 ImportError: dlopen(/OpenCV/StaticLibs/Lib/cv2.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyCObject_Type
or
__ZL13pyopencv_fromIN2cv4MatxIdLi4ELi4EEEEP7_objectRKT_
and so on when python import cv2

```
//your do_not_forget comment here
template<>
PyObject* pyopencv_from(const Matx44d& m) 
{

    Mat temp, *p = (Mat*)&m;
    if(!p->u || p->allocator != &g_numpyAllocator)
    {
        temp.allocator = &g_numpyAllocator;
    }
    PyObject* o = (PyObject*)p->u->userdata;
    Py_INCREF(o);
    return o;
}
```